# PHP - Multiple files Vs single file

Tags: php

I have been playing about with an Ajax/PHP site and I am wondering about the best practices concerning calls to multiple PHP files Vs a single PHP file with many functions in it.

All of these calls are simple database access calls - returning data from a query. It seems a sensible thing to have a single file that opens the database and contains multiple functions, one for each of the calls, however I do not know the best practices in this instance and I am unaware of any security concerns that there may be.

Does anyone know the best practice in this case?

Cheers

BK

Comment: If you are developing in an object oriented manner, you will typically have one PHP file per class.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
I tend toward a single file (I find it a lot easier to read than multiple files) and since there is no-one else to read my code I think Ill go with the single file where appropriate. I was concerned in case there were security implications, but since this does not seem to be the case Ill carry on as I am.
Thanks for your comments - I wont mark an individual answer as correct since they all contribute to the same theme (Is this the correct etiquette for the site?)
regards - Bango

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of opinion, really. If you haven't got much code, and don't intend to re-use any of it elsewhere, you may as well just have it all in one file. You don't want to fall into the trap of over-complicating what might be a simple setup.

If your code starts to build up and become difficult to follow, you will then be better off splitting it across a number of files based on the sort of task they perform. This is the concept frameworks are based on, where maintaining a more complex application structure is more beneficial to your productivity than fumbling with a monolithic `index.php`.

And finally: it is vital to take these considerations into account when expecting *other people* to work with your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is all based on personal preference. Personally, I like to have multiple files as I feel as though it better organizes my code.

However, many people feel as though using only a single file makes locating code more feasible, and thus editing code more efficient.

As far as security is concerned, there is no difference in one using one file verse using multiple - just make sure you are be cautious when coding, not leaving anything open for injection etc.